# Где именно в MySQL в WordPress можно редактировать путь к медиафайлам?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, хостинг

Где именно в MySQL в WordPress можно редактировать путь к медиафайлам?

В самой админке WordPress я нашёл, где именно редактировать, но еще хочу разобраться где именно это в базе данных можно редактировать, и каким способом. Так сказать, изучаю способы решения вопросов разными путями и для общего развития. ))

Буду рад за любую информацию и подсказки, в том числе и любителям рассказать, что кто-то не настолько умный, и задает глупый вопрос.

Скрин приложил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все опции в таблице `wp_options`, ищите ключ и значение.

Comment: @NikPashchuk не нужно давать таких опасных советов. Это ВП, а не простая самоделка.

Comment: @SeVlad Из вопроса, таки именно спрашивали где в БД(`Где именно в MySQL в WordPress ...`), что спросили на то и дал комментарий.

Comment: @NikPashchuk спрашивали про "редактировать". Не нужно вырывать только удобные части вопроса. Отвечая же на полный вопрос ТСа `Где именно в MySQL в WordPress можно редактировать путь к медиафайлам?` ответом будет - НИГДЕ.

Answer (score 0):

> Где именно в MySQL в wordpress вордпресс можно редактировать путь к
>   медиофайлам?

В [конфиге](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_uploads_folder)

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/media' );
```